# Typescript / Angular 2 get method from an other component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component A and component B. In component A i want to make an instance of  component B method addMessage(). I want to make addMessage reusable.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Simple Answer**: In angular 2 if you want to make reusable code, you
>   should write service for that.

1. if you provide service at NgModule() level it will create single
   instance if that service and whole app can use that same instance.
2. or you can provide service at component level so only that component
   can access instance of that service.

Answer (score -1):

We inject component dependency and share the functionalities. I think there is no need to do such instance creation. I may be wrong, what you want to achieve by doing so ?